# Read a city name from a file, include two numbers that represent their distance

Tags: java

I have this program where I have to calculate the closest distance between two "villages" from a text file. The file is stored as for example:

1 2  city1

3 4  city2

5 6  city3

7 8  city4

9 10  city5

The output has to be something like: city1 and city2 are closest with a distance of ...

I have a class Point:

```java
static class Point {
    int x, y;
    
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
 
}
```

How would I effectively loop through this file, and store the integers into the point object and find which of the cities are closer to each other.

Comment: Is this the way to calculate the distance between `city1` and `city2`: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Answer (score 1):

I have hardcode the values.
Please read from file and do in a generic method.
I hope the logic works

```
class Point {
    int x, y;
    String city;
    public Point(int x, int y, String city) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.city = city;
        // getters and setters
    }
}
public static void main(){
    List<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();    
    list.add(new Point(1,2,city1));
    list.add(new Point(3,4,city2));
    list.add(new Point(5,6,city3));
    list.add(new Point(7,8,city4));
    list.add(new Point(9,10,city5));

    if(list.size() < 2){
        System.out.println("Can't find distance");
    }
    Point lowerPoint = null;
    Point upperPoint = null;
    else{
        int min = getDist(list.get(0), list.get(1));
        int dist = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i < list.size(); i++){
            dist = getDist(list.get(i-1), list.get(i));
            if(min > dist){
                min = dist;
                lowerPoint = list.get(i-1);
                upperPoint = list.get(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(min+" "+lowerPoint.getCity()+" "+ upperPoint.getCity());
    }
  
public int getDist(Point p1, Point p2){
    return Math.sqrt((p1.getX()-p2.getX())*(p1.getX()-p2.getX()) + (p1.getY()-p2.getY())*(p1.getY()-p2.getY()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do the following:

- create a City class that has then name and x,y locations.
- then I would have a method that returns the distance from one city to the other.
- it would be called like `city1.getDistance(city2)` where `city1` and `city2` are instances of the `City` class.

```
class City {
    int x, y;
    String name;
    
    public City(int x, int y, String name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public double getDistance(City c) {
        return Math.hypot(this.x-c.x,this.y-c.y);
    }
}
```

- to read in the values, use a `new Scanner();` Check out the documentation on how to use it.
- Then assign the values using`new City(x,y, name)` for each instance and store them in a `List<City>`
- then iterate over the cities, keeping track of the distances and the cities based on the smallest seen thus far.